# how to generate record in table by TCPDF

Tags: php, tcpdf

I am using TCPDF in php but i am facing problem to generate table whole record is not printing in table but it fetching all record in array my code is here

```
<?php
     require_once('lang/eng.php');
     require_once('tcpdf_include.php');

     if (trim($_POST['pdfid']) == "All") {
         $qry = "select master.hcid,hcmaster.hcname,master.instdate,master.sendname,master.address,statemaster.statename,master.district,master.mobile,master.receiptm,master.subject,master.disposal,master.dispdate,MASTER.dispdetail,master.remark
 from master  JOIN hcmaster ON master.hcname=hcmaster.hcid
      JOIN statemaster ON master.state=statemaster.stateid ";
     }
      else {
         $qry = "select master.hcid,hcmaster.hcname,master.instdate,master.sendname,master.address,statemaster.statename,master.district,master.mobile,master.receiptm,master.subject,master.disposal,master.dispdate,MASTER.dispdetail,master.remark
 from master  JOIN hcmaster ON master.hcname=hcmaster.hcid
      JOIN statemaster ON master.state=statemaster.stateid WHERE id = '" . $_POST['pdfid'] . "'";
     }

     if ($qry) {
         $tbdata = '';
         $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "dakmanagement");
         $res = mysqli_query($con, $qry) or die("not fire");



        if (mysqli_num_rows($res)!=0) 
        {
            $i = 1;   
          while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
            {
                            $tbdata .= '<tr><td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td width="10%" align="left">' . $i .
 '</td>
                     <td width="75%"><table width="100%" border="1" cellpadding="2">
                                             <tr>
                            <td width="20%" align="left">Id No:</td>
                            <td width="30%" align="left">' . $row['hcid'] . '</td>
                                                     <td width="20%" align="left">Recv_Mode:</td>
                            <td width="30%" align="left">' . $row['receiptm'] . '</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2" width="20%" align="left">Name:</td>
                                                     <td colspan="2"  width="80%" align="left">' . $row['hcname'] . '</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2"  width="20%" align="left">Subject:</td>
                            <td colspan="2"  width="80%" align="left">' . $row['subject'] . '</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2"  width="20%" align="left">Address:</td>
                            <td colspan="2"  width="80%" align="left">' . $row['address'] . '</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2"  width="20%" align="left">Disp_dtls:</td>
                            <td colspan="2"  width="80%" align="left">' . $row['dispdate'] . '-' . $row['dispdetail'] . '</td>
                        </tr>
                </table></td>
                             <td width="15%" align="right">' . $row['instdate'] . '<br/>' . $row['dispdate'] . '</td></tr>
                             ';
                    $i++;

                }
         }

     // create new PDF document
         $pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

     // set document information
        $pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
         $pdf->SetAuthor('Vinay Soni');
         $pdf->SetTitle('High Court');
         $pdf->SetSubject('High Court');
         $pdf->SetKeywords('High Court');


     // set margins
         $pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
         $pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
         $pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);

     // set auto page breaks
         $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);

     // set some language-dependent strings (optional)
         if (@file_exists(dirname(__FILE__) . '/lang/eng.php')) {
             require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/lang/eng.php');
             $pdf->setLanguageArray($l);
         }

     // ---------------------------------------------------------
     // set font
         $pdf->SetFont('dejavusans', '', 10);

     // add a page
         $pdf->AddPage();

     // writeHTML($html, $ln=true, $fill=false, $reseth=false, $cell=false, $align='')
     // writeHTMLCell($w, $h, $x, $y, $html='', $border=0, $ln=0, $fill=0, $reseth=true, $align='', $autopadding=true)
     // create some HTML content
         $html = '
     <div style="width:100%; float:left;">
        <p style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 20px; text-align: center;">RAJASTHAN HIGH COURT BENCH JAIPUR.<br/>
            <span style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 18px; text-align: center;">Hon`ble CJ Secretariat</span>
        </p>
     </div>    
     <table width="100%" border="1">
        <tr >
            <th align="left">S.No.</th>
            <th align="center">Complete Detail of Records</th>
            <th align="right"  >Inst_date<br/>Disp_date</th>
        </tr>
        ' . $tbdata . '
     </table>
     ';
     // output the HTML content
        $pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');

     // reset pointer to the last page
         $pdf->lastPage();

    //Close and output PDF document
         $pdf->Output('Report.pdf', 'I');
     }
     ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This link will help you try to use table in pdf
http://phppot.com/demo/generate-pdf-from-mysql-data-using-fpdf/